# Would Making My Literature Review Open Source Be Beneficial to Others in Academia?

Tags: academic-life, literature-review, intellectual-property, open-science, public-domain

I am currently working on a comprehensive literature review for a paper in my field of study. As I delve deeper into this project, I am considering the possibility of making the literature review open source. My primary motivation is to potentially aid other researchers and students who are exploring similar topics.

Given the extensive effort of compiling a literature review, including the analysis and summarization of numerous sources, I am curious about the academic community's perspective on the value of open-source literature reviews. Would such a resource be considered beneficial and utilized by others in academia?

Furthermore, I am interested in understanding any potential drawbacks or challenges associated with making a literature review open source. Are there copyright or intellectual property concerns I should be aware of? Also, what would be the best platforms or methods to share an open-source literature review to ensure it reaches the intended audience effectively?

Comment: What do you mean by "open source?" A literature review is not code.

Comment: Similarly, what do you mean by a 'literature review'? Obviously there are many thousands of review articles which review the literature in a particular (sub-)field, are you simply proposing something like that, or something else?

Comment: I think public-domain is what is intended, @MichaelGreinecker.

Comment: Not to be mean, but I voted to close this question unless it is thoroughly revised. As @MichaelGreinecker commented, "open source" does not apply to literature reviews, yet that is the whole point of the question. So, the question is nonsensical and cannot be answered in its present form. I sincerely have no idea what you are asking. I know that Buffy thinks you mean public domain, but that is not the same thing as open source. Please completely revise the question using appropriate terminology so that we can try to help you.

Comment: I agree with @Tripartio and voted to close it. It needs more clarity, I don't understand what open source means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I think that making a literature review "open source" (or rather "public domain") has no effect at all, and does nothing to help others. Sorry.

First, there is the question of whether a literature review is a creative work or not. In many cases it isn't making not subject to copyright in the first place. Certainly there are exceptions to that. Normally, though, collections of citations have little creative content.

However, someone who need to reuse what you have done still need to cite properly everything from your lit review that you have included.

You may be confusing plagiarism and copyright. Open source involves only the latter. People still need to cite sources to avoid plagiarism and misattribution of ideas.

And if someone else wants to use your lit review verbatim, they still need to cite you to avoid plagiarism, though there would be no copyright violation if it is open source.

---

Plagiarism and copyright are orthogonal in some sense. You can have either, both, or neither. Transgressions of both need to be avoided.

Comment: It has no substantial effect compared to any other open access way of publishing. It certainly has an effect compared to putting the paper behind a paywall.